# max,min aggregate functions in mysql does not returns row assosiated with that max or min value

Tags: mysql

I am using max function in query. It returns me max value for that column but it not returns other columns associated with that max value. It returns max value for that column and for other columns returns values from first row in which where clause matched. I find way through order by desc and limit 1 but Is it right way for that ?

Any help in finding right way. Thanks in Advance

Comment: No, it's not right. And such a query does not return the "first row", see [MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html): **The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.**

Comment: Just look around SO. This is the most FAQ under the MySQL tag

Comment: There's a section in the manual describing exactly this problem: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: @vmai maybe so, but if you select from an inner ordered query result, I defy you to produce results for any rows other than the first encountered.

Comment: @Bohemian Troublemaker ;-)